# Problem with Elasticsearch querying nested documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am learning ES and I am having problems with this query:

Given 2 products:

```
products/_source/1
{
  "product_id": "58410-2",
  "name": [
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "translation": "CBC panel"
    },
    {
      "locale": "vn",
      "translation": "CBC panel VN"
    }
  ],
  "status": "active",
  "category": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": [
      {
        "locale": "en",
        "translation": "Hematology"
      },
      {
        "locale": "vn",
        "translation": "huyết học"
      }
    ]
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "product_id": "6690-2",
      "name": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "translation": "Leukocytes"
        },
        {
          "locale": "vn",
          "translation": "Leukocytes vn"
        }
      ],
      "status": "active",
      "category": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": [
          {
            "locale": "en",
            "translation": "Hematology"
          },
          {
            "locale": "vn",
            "translation": "huyết học"
          }
        ]
      },
      "children": []
    }]}
```

and

```
products/_source/2
{
  "product_id": "6690-2",
  "name": [
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "translation": "Leukocytes"
    },
    {
      "locale": "vn",
      "translation": "Leukocytes vn"
    }
  ],
  "status": "active",
  "category": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": [
      {
        "locale": "en",
        "translation": "Hematology"
      },
      {
        "locale": "vn",
        "translation": "huyết học"
      }
    ]
  },
  "children": []
}
```

where a product is a single document but also can be nested in a `children` array of other products. Both products are different documents in the index.

and this index:

```
{
  "products": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "properties": {
                "locale": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "translation": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "name": {
          "properties": {
            "locale": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "translation": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "product_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "provided_name": "products",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to query for "Leuko" (or the category or the product_id) and retrieve both products, the single product and the root product.

I have tried using object field, nested, flattened but I think the problem is I don't know how to properly write the query, I have tried things like this (I am using a ruby library but I think it is easy to follow):

```
    @query = { 
      query: {
        query_string: { 
          fields: ['name.translation', 'children.name.translation', 'category.name.translation', 'children.product_id'],
          query: "*#{text}*" 
        }
      },
      size: 50
    }
```

```
@query = {
      query: {
        nested: {
          path: 'children',
          query: {
            bool: {
              should: [
                term: { 'children.name.translation' => "*#{text}*" },
                term: { 'name.translation' => "*#{text}*" }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

but I think at some point I dunno what I am doing anymore and I am just randomly trying different stuff from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow my query suggestion. Note that I had to add the fields in the Nested object to the mapping.

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "properties": {
              "locale": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "translation": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "children": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "product_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "category": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "properties": {
                  "locale": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "translation": {
                    "type": "text"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "properties": {
              "locale": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "translation": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "name": {
        "properties": {
          "locale": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "translation": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "product_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "children",
            "query": {
              "wildcard": {
                "children.name.translation": "leuko*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name.translation": "leuko*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**hint**

See that you use translation. Avoid using array to make your queries simpler.
What I would do in your case is to create a field for each language, this makes the use of analyzer more flexible for each type of language and you stop using an array and work with an object.

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "es":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer":"english"
          },
          "vn":{
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/
{
  "name": "Leukocytes"
}
```

An example query using field languages.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Leukocytes",
      "fields": ["name.es", "name.vn"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see your approach, but then it won't work if I have more nest levels, right? if the product children has more product children?